# Is it possible to perform a non interactive (bot) login for iphone without betfair SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, betfair

## Non interactive login in betfair

Is it possible to perform a non interactive (bot) login for iphone without betfair SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - the API is not greatly documented, but you can find the direct HTTP requests when you look into the JavaScript API:

https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Javascript

Answer (score 0):

sure it is possible. i guess you want to get into millionaire's club :)

0) i will assume that you already have [betfair developer account](https://register.betfair.com/account/registration) & registered application

1) clone [betFairNonInteractive](https://github.com/ha100/betFairNonInteractive) project

2) follow the steps at [BETFAIR's Non-Interactive (bot) login](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Non-Interactive+%28bot%29+login) to generate certificates

3) import **client-2048.crt** & **client-2048.pkcs12** into the sample project

[image: betfair non-interactive (bot) login]

4) update the certificatePassword value in **Networking.m** class with password used during certificate generation process

5) update BETFAIR_appKey, BETFAIR_product, BETFAIR_username, BETFAIR_password values in **BETFAIR_MutableURLRequest.m** class

6) build & run - you should get your account details back

7) [aping-ios-sdk](https://github.com/betfair/aping-ios-sdk) is well written and good source for learning

8) start reading books on technical analysis ;)